# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'uuid' in 'field list'

Tags: laravel

I use in my laravel project package to save image `spatie/laravel-medialibrary`, but when I want to save
image it gives me an error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: ***Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'uuid' in 'field list'***
```

I send my migration table

[image]

If anyone can help me I would be glad.

Thank you.

Comment: Your table doesn't has a `uuid` field,  Post your controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the documentation, you should run:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaLibraryServiceProvider" --tag="migrations"
```

and

```
php artisan migrate
```